# In Tkinter how do I make it so when a "Show Password button" is clicked it is switched with a "Hide password" button

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am doing a school projects and very much need help. The code I have tried is below:

```
  def ShowPassword():
    PasswordEntry = tk.Entry(window, show="", font=2)
    canvas1.create_window(250, 230, window=PasswordEntry)
    ShowPasswordButton.destroy()
    canvas1.create_window(420, 230, window=HidePasswordButton)

def HidePassword():
    PasswordEntry = tk.Entry(window, show="*", font=2)
    canvas1.create_window(250, 230, window=PasswordEntry)
    HidePasswordButton.destroy()
    canvas1.create_window(420, 230, window=ShowPasswordButton)


ShowPasswordButton = tk.Button(window, height=1, width=12, text= "Show Password", command=ShowPassword)
canvas1.create_window(420, 230, window=ShowPasswordButton)
HidePasswordButton = tk.Button(window, height=1, width=12, text="Hide Password", command=HidePassword)
```

The program switches from Show password to Hide Password once and then after that the button just disapears. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: First of all why are you creating all of your widgets inside a canvas? Also instead of creating a new entry use: `<tk.Entry>.config(show=...)` to change the entry's attributes.

Comment: This is my first time using Tkinter and my school never actually taught me it so thats just how I have found works, what is wrong with using canvas and what would you recommend I use instead? Thanks

Comment: You can use `<your widget>.place(x=x, y=y)` to place your widgets. That uses the `.place` geometry manager. `tkinter` has 3 geometry managers: [`.place(...)`](http://web.archive.org/web/20201111222928/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm), [`.pack(...)`](http://web.archive.org/web/20201111222645/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm) and [`.grid(...)`](http://web.archive.org/web/20201111175154/http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it does not work is because you destroy the button and don't create it again, but your current method is a bit impractical. Here is a more straightforward approach:

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
passwordShown = False

def passToggle():
    global passwordShown
    if passwordShown: #If the password is being shown, hide it
        passwordShown = False
        PasswordEntry.config(show = "*")
        ShowPasswordButton.config(text = "Show Password")
    else: #If the password is not visible, show it
        passwordShown = True
        PasswordEntry.config(show = "")
        ShowPasswordButton.config(text = "Hide Password")

PasswordEntry = tk.Entry(window, show = "*", font = 2)
PasswordEntry.pack()
ShowPasswordButton = tk.Button(window, height = 1, width = 12, text = "Show Password", command = passToggle)
ShowPasswordButton.pack()
```

This uses a function to show/hide the password and change what the button says. It doesn't use the canvas, because that it not necessary. Instead, it used a geometry manager (tells Tkinter where to put things) called `pack`. This just places the widget (buttons, labels, etc.) under the previous one. There are two other geometry managers, `grid` and `place`. `grid` arranges items in a grid and `place` places a widget at the coordinates you give it.
Now there is a single Entry and a single Button. When the button is clicked, the entry and button are changed by the `passToggle` function. The `passwordShown` variable keeps track of whether the password is showing or not. If the password is showing, `passwordShown` is set to False so next time the button is pressed it does the opposite. Then the Entry is changed using the `.config` method to show "*" for letters and changes the button text to "Show Password". If `passwordShown` is False, it does the opposite.

Comment: Instead of using `passwordShown` you can use `PasswordEntry.cget("show") != "*"`

Comment: That's a good idea but it makes it slightly less readable.

Comment: True. I would just use a variable too but some people on stackoverflow really hate global variables. I don't know if OP likes them or not so I just put it in the comments :D

Comment: Thanks alot for both your help got it working now using your method thanks.